# Operation not permitted when running a Haskell program on OS X

Tags: haskell, runtime-error, osx-mountain-lion

I am writing my first Haskell program, a web application based on the Yesod framework.

I compiled the code using `cabal configure && cabal build`. When I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

```
-bash: dist/build/MyApp/MyApp: Operation not permitted
```

I installed the 64-bit Haskell platform (2012.2.0.0) on OS X Mountain Lion. I had originally installed the 32-bit version, but got the same error, so I uninstalled it and tried the 64-bit version.

The application compiles and links with no errors or warnings.

I even tried the fix described in http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57374676-263/workarounds-for-quarantine-bug-in-os-x-lion/, but it made no difference.

**UPDATE:** The plot thickens. The source tree is actually on an encrypted sparse bundle (all of my source code is). When I copy the tree to my home directory, it compiles **and runs**.

The mount command does not show the *noexec* option:

```
/dev/disk2s9 on /Volumes/Personal (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners, quarantine, mounted by grk)
```

I'm not sure about the *quarantine* option, but I suspect it comes from Symantec Endpoint Protection (required by my employer). I'll try disabling it for the sparse bundle.

Comment: Have you tried adding executable permissions with `chmod +x dist/build/MyApp/MyApp`?

Comment: I did not mention it in my question, but file is already executable (rwxr-xr-x).

Comment: You might try compiling and running a simple Hello World type application and see whether that works OK or not...

Comment: See the update to my question above. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at the sister site apple.stackexchange.com: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/mount-is-adding-a-quarantine-flag-causing-bin-bash-bad-interpreter-operatio

The sparse bundle is actually marked with the *quarantine* flag. I unmounted the volume and removed the quarantine with the following command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Personal.sparsebundle
```

then remounted. Problem solved.